# Prove that this inequality holds for a constant $c$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

The problem is, Prove that there exists a constant $c>0$, such that $\forall x$$\in[1,\infty]$,  $$\sum_{n= x}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2} \le \frac{c}{x}\ .$$

now if $n\in N$, this is obvious as 
  $\sum_{n\ge x}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ will obviously be convergent hence we can surely find such a $c\gt0$. But I doubt wheather it is true for all real $x\in[1,\infty]$. as say we take any interval $(a,a+1)\in [1,\infty]$. in this interval only, of course there are uncountably infinite real numbers. So how to find such $c$ when $x$ takes any real value?

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the notation: $\sum_{n=x}^\infty$ means that $n$ takes all **integer** values from $x$ upwards.  That is, $n$ has to be an integer even if $x$ is not.  For example, if $x=\pi$ then $n$ will take the values $4,5,6,\ldots\,$.

Comment: By Cesàro-Stolz
$$ \lim_{m\to +\infty} m\sum_{n\geq m}\frac{1}{n^2} = \lim_{m\to +\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{m^2}}{\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+1}} = 1 $$

Comment: Yeah, thank you @David for pointing out my misunderstanding. Now I understood.

Comment: Doesn't the closed interval $[1, \infty]$ not make sense, since you can't reach $\infty$ since $\infty = \infty + 1$ (it is a mere concept)? Shouldn't it be written as the open interval $(0, \infty)$ instead? An example to demonstrate what I mean can be found here $\longrightarrow$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2364027/prove-that-forall-x-0-x-1-ge-lnx?rq=1 -- Just curious is all...

Comment: @user477343 You are right here, but see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you very much!! I have never heard of this, so thank you for showing me this link :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n= x}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2} \le\int_{x-1}^\infty\frac{dt}{t^2}=\frac1{x-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

taking into account David's comment on how to interpret the question, show that on the interval $[1,\infty)$ the graph of $f(x)=\frac{c}{x^2}$ will lie above the piecewise constant function $g(x)=\frac1{\lfloor x^2 \rfloor}$ when $c \gt 4$.