# How to prove $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}=O(\frac{1}{n})$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, inequality, asymptotics

I would like to prove $$\sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\leq \frac{C}{n},$$where $C$ is independent of $n$.

**My Attempt:**

Since $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}$ is convergent, there exists $N=N(n)$ such that if $k>N$, there holds
$$\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}<\frac1n$$
This implies that
$$\sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}= \sum\limits_{k=n}^{N}\frac{1}{k^2}+\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}<\frac{N-n+1}{n^2}+\frac1n$$
However, I found the integer $N$ here is dependent of $n$.

Is there a smart and correct way to prove this inequality? Any insight or help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the integral test? Its proof solves your problem.

Comment: Not so familiar. Could you give some concrete details or references?

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2591225/42969

Answer (score -2, accepted):

$$\frac1n=\int_{n}^\infty\frac1{x^2}dx\le\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\le \int_{n-1}^\infty\frac1{x^2}dx=\frac1{n-1}$$

Comment: This has been asked and answered more than once.